# Timestamp in database dedicated for an agent

Tags: database-design, timestamp, agent

I need to design a database for a software agent. There should be some tables (eg. DOOR, CORRIDOR, WINOW) indicating objects with columns for specific features. Features may be set, unset or unavailable. They should be also somehow localised according to time when they occured.

One of main tasks will be checking what features the object had in particular moment of the time. There should be easy way of getting features for the timestamp which is closest for given parameter (also of timestamp type).

The program handling it would be in Java. It's going to be small application. I'm thinking about JavaDB - it doesn't have to be efficient but I'm open for other suggestions.
Timestamp is an abstract concept here. It can be just in continuous integers. The problem will occur when the agent gathers information from the DB and associate timestamp for two or more objects. They can vary but should be treated as *the same moment* in some scope.

Should I place timestamp columns in each table or should I rather do it another way? What do you think is the best approach for this?

Comment: What database are you using? And please be specific about what you mean by "timestamp". The name has different meanings in different databases (ie. in SQL Server is does **not** identify a moment in time).

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I don't fell like I really understand what you're getting at just by reading your description.

But I think you're going to have to store a timestamp column in each table. I'm imagining features like "door keypad" and "door open sensor" for an intrusion monitoring system. You might want to distinguish a "normal" door event--a "door keypad" event followed by a "unlock door" event followed by a "door open" event, all within 5 seconds--from an intrusion event (2 minutes to bypass the lock). So I don't think integers will help you here.